# insert multiple form data in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am really unsure why I am unable to insert data into my table based on a foreach loop.  The form that is Posting the data is created using this code:

```
<?php

        $eventList = query("SELECT event FROM PrimaryEvents");

        foreach ($eventList as $row)
        {
        //build the form
                echo("<div class='form-group'>");
                        echo("<label for='{$row["event"]}' class='col-lg-2 control-label'>'{$row["event"]}'</label>");
                        echo("<div class='col-lg-10'>");
                        echo("<input type='number' class='form-control' id='{$row["event"]}' name='{$row["event"]}' placeholder='????'>");
                echo("</div>");
                        echo("</div>");

        }

?>
```

The $eventList array contains a list of event names.

When it comes to updating the database I have tried this code which isnt working:

```
        $eventList = query("SELECT event FROM PrimaryEvents");
        logConsole(' eventlist is: ', $eventList, true);

        foreach ($eventList as $row)
        {
        query("INSERT INTO logbook ('{$row["event"]}') VALUES (?)", $_POST['{$row["event"]}']);
        }
```

I have searched and searched but havent found a solution.  I have tried a few variations on the $row["event], '$row["event"] etc but have tried so many now I am starting to get confused.

I always treated '' to mean php would take the text from between the '' and not the variable value itself.

Thanks for any help;

Andy

EDIT1:

Code updated to the suggestion below from fiction but I am still getting the following error :

```
Notice: Undefined index: Test Event in /var/www/NST/public/input.php on line 53

Fatal error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Event) VALUES (?)' at line 1 in /var/www/NST/includes/functions.php on line 164
```

The event name is 'Test Event'.  If I use the code on a event with name 'testevent' then it works just fine.

Code based on fiction answer looks like:

```
        $eventList = query("SELECT event FROM PrimaryEvents");

        foreach ($eventList as $row)
        {    
        $event = trim($row['event']);
        $str = "INSERT INTO logbook (".$event.") VALUES (?)";
        query($str, $_POST[$event]);
        }
```

Also, I would like all of the event data to be added to the same entry of the database (currently each time through the loop writes a new line and increments the primary id).

Thanks for the help so far!

EDIT2:  Form updated now as per fictions suggestion.  Code now reads:

```
<?php

        $eventList = query("SELECT event FROM PrimaryEvents");

        foreach ($eventList as $row)
        {
        //build the form
                echo("<div class='form-group'>");
                        echo("<label for='".$row["event"]."' class='col-lg-2 control-label'>'".$row["event"]."'</label>");
                        echo("<div class='col-lg-10'>");
                        echo("<input type='number' class='form-control' id='".$row["event"]."' name='".$row["event"]."' placeholder='????'>");
                    echo("</div>");
                echo("</div>");

        }

?>
```

Chrome inspect shows the element is named correctly:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="Test Event" name="Test Event" placeholder="????">
```

I am still getting an error when I try to write to the table.  print_r($_POST) shows that the INSERT INTO is still trying to write to TEST_EVENT.

Comment: What does your `query()` function do....

Comment: how are you posting the data to save it? is it on form submit?

Comment: try dumping the data if it is present or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace this code inside foreach:

```
query("INSERT INTO logbook ('{$row["event"]}') VALUES (?)", $_POST['{$row["event"]}']);
```

with this code:

```
$event = trim($row['event']);
$str = "INSERT INTO logbook (".$event.") VALUES (?)";
query($str, $_POST[$event]);
```

This should fix your problem

Also change fix your form-paste code to:

```
<?php

    $eventList = query("SELECT event FROM PrimaryEvents");

    foreach ($eventList as $row)
    {
    //build the form
            echo("<div class='form-group'>");
                    echo("<label for='".$row["event"]."' class='col-lg-2 control-label'>'".$row["event"]."'</label>");
                    echo("<div class='col-lg-10'>");
                    echo("<input type='number' class='form-control' id='".$row["event"]."' name='".$row["event"]."' placeholder='????'>");
            echo("</div>");
                    echo("</div>");

    }

?>
```

Comment: I am getting an undefined index error if the event name has a space in it.  How can I handle that? Also, how would I modify this so that it inserts into logbook at $_SESSION["id"]?  I have tried to modify as follows: $str = "INSERT INTO logbook (id, ".$event.") VALUES (?,?)", $_SESSION["id"], $_POST[$event]; but it isnt working.

Comment: If it has space you can filter it with function trim - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.trim.php

In my example you will need to change this string:
$event = $row['event'];
to
$event = trim($row['event']);

I edit my answer

Comment: Do you have a column Test Event in your database logbook?
And do you have a key Test Event in your $_POST? 
Call print_r($_POST) before foreach

Comment: Edit to my question.  Still having a similar error with the SPACE handling even with the updated form.